# Usage of Determiner “some”

Tags: sentence-meaning

Does the determiner “some” also describe “milk” in the sentence below? Or it only describes “bread”?
I’d like some bread and milk.

Comment: It would defy common sense if 'some' didn't apply to the milk.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do believe that it would also describe "milk" there. At least, "I would like some bread and some milk" sounds exactly the same, if not repetitive.
When multiple items are listed, any adjectives generally carry over unless specified else. See this:

> I saw a lot of red cars and trucks.

Here, both the cars and the trucks are red, as there is no adjective before "truck." Compare this to:

> I saw a lot of red cars and blue trucks.

Here, only the cars are red, as the trucks are described by the adjective "blue."
Thus, in "I would like some bread and milk," "some" carries over to "milk."

Comment: So in “I saw a lot of red cars and trucks.”, “a lot of red” carries over to “trucks”, right?

Comment: Yes, both the phrase "a lot of" and the adjective "red" modify the cars and the trucks, so the phrase is essentially the same as "I saw a lot of red cars and a lot of red trucks." We just don't say this because it's unnecessarily long.

Comment: @user10871523 It's possible that it isn't meant to "carry over," but if you don't want anybody assuming it does, you need to provide explicit qualifiers for the second item. (1) *I saw a lot of red cars and two trucks.* (2) *I saw a lot of red cars but only one truck.* (3) *I saw a lot of red cars. I also saw trucks.*